# android change device screen resolution pragmatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin, adb

I want to change device resolution and density for a special purpose within my android app.
I found out that using `adb` there is a command to do so. 
like this

```
adb shell wm size 1270x720

and then

adb shell wm density 200
```

and I also heard that can run `adb` command using within the app but it seems not to work.

```
cmd1 = "wm size 1270x720"
cmd2 = "wm density 200"
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd 1/2).waitFor()
```

Comment: Have you Tryied it on a root device?

Comment: I tested the app on a device that is system signed, but app is not installed in priv-app

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out after hours of trial and error. I used error `errorStream` instead of `inputStream`, since commands run into error their input was empty.

```
    val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
    val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(
        InputStreamReader(process.errorStream)
    )

    // Grab the results
    val log = StringBuilder()
    var line: String?
    line = bufferedReader.readLine()
    while (line != null) {
        log.append(line + "\n")
        line = bufferedReader.readLine()
    }
    Log.i("ADB_COMMAND", "command : $command $log")
```

after that fix was in plain sight. I was missing `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission.